# Буфер обмена в PHP?

Tags: php

Функция добавления в буфер обмена в PHP

Comment: А вы на пхп случайно не Ворд пишете? (; Объясните, в какой буфер обмена вы собираетесь копировать из скрипта, выполняемого на сервере? Или вы тролль?

Comment: Что Вы подразумеваете под буфером обмена ?

Comment: Доставило, спасибо, особенно некоторые из ответов :)

Comment: Слушай, а зачем тебе вообще пользоваться буфером обмена? В этом 
абсолютно нет никакого смысла. Переменные в PHP не имеют никаких 
ограничений по памяти и по типу, так, что в конце-то концов пользуйся
 суперглобальными массивами. Один из таких - массив $_SESSION[];

Answer (score 1):

http://phpfaq.ru/na_tanke
Посмотри мож покопаешся !

Answer (score 1):

Фактически, чистым PHP это сделать невозможно! Да и невозможно вообще! PHP - это веб-серерный язык программирования, а не системный.

Answer (score 1):

```
ob_start();
echo 'blablabla';
mySuperFunctionThatDisplaysSomething();
$buff = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_flush();
```

Оно?

Answer (score 0):

Как таковой функции нету, может есть какая библиотека в PEAR, сам не интересовался, поэтому подсказать не могу.

Comment: информативно)))

Comment: Я не знаю ответа, но мне так хотелось ответить :DDD